# WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL. Go exactly to #label

Tags: android, android-webview

How to go EXACTLY to http://example.com/index.html#label if content to webview loading via WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL ?
By default webview go to root only. How go to label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView doesn't have such functionality from the box.
You can achieve this with the help of javascript, but this is a bit of ugly.
You should load your html page and then add javascript code to it.
After this you can load your webview and call javascript methods from current page.

Check this link for example how that can be done.

[WebView jump to anchor using loadDataWithBaseUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062901/webview-jump-to-anchor-using-loaddatawithbaseurl)

Answer (score 0):

Example goes here

webContents.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          String id = "895884";
          webContents.loadUrl("javascript:scrollAnchor(" + id + ");");
    }

});
```