# How to jump to anchor in android WebView that loads html from string source?

Tags: android, webview

There is a code of WebView:

```
WebView webView;
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.text_web_view);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<a name=\"#ancor1\"></a><p name=\"anchor2\"></p>", null, "utf-8", null);
```

how to jump to anchor2 in this case?

Comment: Still actual. Is it really so strange practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062901/webview-jump-to-anchor-using-loaddatawithbaseurl helped me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Enable JS in Activity class declaration

   @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
   public class ReadLawActivity extends AppCompatActivity { ... }
2. Run this code

   String script = String.format("javascript:jumpTo(\"item%d\")", item.getItemId());

Comment: `jumpTo` is not defined.  also this assumes the id of the element will start with "item" and end with a number